# Clean way to run multiple sequential functions on the same dataset

Tags: python, function

Using Python, I am running a series of preprocessing functions on a list, like this:

```
my_list0 = [1, 2, 3, ...]

my_list1 = function_foo(my_list0)
my_list2 = function_bar(my_list1)
my_list3 = function_fizz(my_list2)
my_list4 = function_buzz(my_list3)
```

Is there a more sophisticated way of laying this out?
It gets the job done but it feels like it could be more elegant?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this reminds a pipeline design pattern.

You can use a simple wrapper methods to help with that:

```
def pipeline(data, *filters):
    for filter in filters:
        data = filter(data)
    return data
```

And then you can  use:

```
pipeline([1,2,3], foo, bar, fizz, buzz)
```

Comment: I think this is the neatest because it's the most function-agnostic - I don't have to hard-code the functions in the pipeline. Thank you - I will use this :)

Comment: what is the name of such design pattern?

Comment: @SenthilkumarM, I usually refer to this as the "pipes and filters" design pattern or architectural pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put the function names into a list and iterate over them:

```py
functions = [function_foo, function_bar, function_fizz, function_buzz]

result = my_list0
for f in functions:
    result = f(result)

print(result)
```

This way, if you only need to maintain the list of functions (add, remove, reorder) without changing the code which iterates through them.

Answer (score 1):

```
def preprocess_list(my_list):
    return function_buzz(function_fizz(function_bar(function_foo(my_list))))

my_list0 = [1, 2, 3, ...]
preprocessed_list = preprocess_list(my_list0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all functions take the same parameter(s) you can write it:

```
my_list0 = [1, 2, 3, ...]

actions = [function_foo, function_bar, function_fizz, function_buzz]

my_list = my_list0

for a in actions:
    my_list = a(my_list)
```

Comment: What if they don't?

Comment: @travelsandbooks so you be forced to iterate over params as well, but first zip them: actions and params list, in same position that they will be call

Comment: @travelsandbooks Depending on the situation the solution must either be modified (e. g. with lambda-wrappers) or the solution can't be used.